# What is the best way of categorising segments of a time period?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a staff rota system. For payroll I need to calculate the correct rate of pay depending on the date/time period the shift covers.

How can I check for various date periods (weekend, holidays, weekday) without using a long chain of conditional statements with lengthy, verbose conditions.

Given any time range (a shift):

eg. 2015-01-20 15:00 --> 2015-01-21 17:00

What would be the best (and most efficient way) of categorising segments of the this period?

I would like to know:

- The period (if any) between 22:00 and 07:00 on any weekday (Monday -
  Friday) evening.
- The period (if any) falling between 08:00 on a Saturday and 22:00 on a Sunday.
- The period (if any) falling on a public holiday (using the
  [holidays gem](https://github.com/alexdunae/holidays))

So my two questions then are:

1) Knowing that a time period (shift) could span a weekend (although I would prefer a solution that would support a span of many days), how do I calculate which date/time ranges to compare against?

2) Once I have determined the time periods (weekends, holidays etc) to compare against, how do I best determine the intersection of these periods and determine the duration of them?

Comment: Doing some comparisons? I'm not sure what the question is, or what you'd expect to be able to do other than doing some comparisons (whether or not those comparisons are wrapped up in methods).

Comment: I have a solution using comparisons. It's a mess. I was wondering if this was a known problem, and I'm not using the right terminology to describe it?

Comment: Can you give some context around the categorizations? What is the use case for these categories?

Comment: Sure @eabraham it's for a staff rota system. A shift has to be broken down for reporting reasons and payroll. Ie weekend hours are to be paid at a different rate than weekday hours. Thanks.

Comment: I feel like this question was placed on hold too quickly. Yes, the asker should have been more specific but the problem can be identified by asking a few probing questions.

Comment: Thanks @eabraham :) I have searched extensively for solutions in this area but I do feel it's a problem that others may well encounter in a variety of contexts.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have edited this question quite a lot, as has eabraham. Would you please reopen it or advise me what else to do to improve it? Thank you.

Comment: Just voted to reopen; this is badly-titled at the moment and isn't going to be easily found by Googlers (not sure how to improve it though), but it's a genuinely interesting and entirely valid question that I don't think should've been closed. However, personally I think the question was better *before* you edited it. Maybe I'm too tired, but I had to reread the edited version three times before I understood it; the original is immediately clear and gets to the point.

Comment: Thanks @MarkAmery :) ahh I can't win! :/

Comment: Don't give up! My suggestions: 1) Change the title to something like: "How do I compute payroll when rates of pay vary by time period". That is, change the focus from "categorizing segements" to calculating pay per shift. 2) Give the formula for calculating pay for each shift worked, with one or two examples.  I'm guessing it's something like `h1*r1 + h2*r2`, where `h1` and `h2` are the numbers of hours in periods 1 and 2 and `r1` and `r2` are pay per hour in each of those periods. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) 3) Give a specific definition of periods, even if it's a simplification of the actual situation (as you can adapt solutions to your needs). Perhaps you could use just four: `midnight-8am weekdays`, ``8am-4pm weekdays`, `4pm-midnight weekdays`` and weekends (i.e., all other hours). 4) Give example data for one employee. That would be shifts worked over a pay period (say one week), with the start date, start time and end time given for each shift work, and the employee's pay per hour for each of the periods (say four) defined earlier, if not a  holiday and the same if a holiday.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, so I've put together some code that is based on many assumptions about the problem you face. I hope some of the issues I've addressed, and the way I've dealt with them, may be helpful to you. For example, if a worker is still working when a shift ends, it is necessary to identify the next shift, which may be the next day.

You'll see that my code is very rough and poorly structured. I have many temporary variables that are there just to help you follow what's going on. In a real app, you might want to add some classes, more methods, etc. Also, assuming the data will be stored in a database, you might want to use SQL for some of the calculations.

First, what I've assumed to be the data.

**Data**

A list of holidays:

```
holidays = ["2015:04:05", "2015:04:06"]
```

Information for each employee, including the employee's job classification, with keys being the employee id:

```
employees = {
  123 => { name: 'Bob', job: :worker_bee1 },
  221 => { name: 'Sue', job: :worker_bee2 }
}
```

Groups of days having the same daily periods, with pay rates the same for all days of the group, for each job and period within the day, unless the day falls on a holiday:

```
day_groups = { weekdays: [1,2,3,4,5], weekends: [6,0] }
```

Information for each work period:

```
work_periods = {  
  weekday_graveyard: {
    day_group: :weekdays,
    start_time: "00:00", 
    end_time:   "08:00" },
  weekday_day: {
    day_group: :weekdays,
    start_time: "08:00", 
    end_time:   "16:00" },
  weekday_swing: {
    day_group: :weekdays,
    start_time: "16:00", 
    end_time:   "24:00" },
  weekend: {
    day_group: :weekends,
    start_time: "00:00", 
    end_time:   "24:00" } }
```

A wage schedule by job, dialy period, for non-holidays and holidays:

```
wage_by_job = {
  worker_bee1: {
    weekday_graveyard: { standard: 30.00, holiday: 60.00 },
    weekday_day:       { standard: 20.00, holiday: 40.00 },
    weekday_swing:     { standard: 25.00, holiday: 50.00 },
    weekend:           { standard: 22.00, holiday: 44.00 }
  },
  worker_bee2: {
    weekday_graveyard: { standard: 32.00, holiday: 64.00 },
    weekday_day:       { standard: 22.00, holiday: 44.00 },
    weekday_swing:     { standard: 27.00, holiday: 54.00 },
    weekend:           { standard: 24.00, holiday: 48.00 }
  }
}
```

Hours worked by all employees during the pay period:

```
shifts_worked = [
  { id: 123, date: "2015:04:03", start_time: "15:30", end_time: "00:15" },
  { id: 221, date: "2015:04:04", start_time: "23:30", end_time: "08:30" },
  { id: 123, date: "2015:04:06", start_time: "08:00", end_time: "16:00" },
  { id: 221, date: "2015:04:06", start_time: "23:00", end_time: "07:00" },
  { id: 123, date: "2015:04:07", start_time: "00:00", end_time: "09:00" }
]
```

**Helpers**

```
require 'set'
require 'date'

def date_str_to_obj(date_str)
  Date.strptime(date_str, '%Y:%m:%d')
end

  date_str_to_obj("2015:04:04")
    #=> #<Date: 2015-04-04 ((2457117j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

def next_day(day)
  (day==6) ? 0 : day+1
end

  next_day(6)
    #=> 0
```

Convert holidays to date objects and store in a set for fast lookup:

```
@holiday_set = Set.new(holidays.map { |date_str| 
  date_str_to_obj(date_str) }.to_set)
  #=> #<Set: {#<Date: 2015-04-05 ((2457118j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #           #<Date: 2015-04-06 ((2457119j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}> 

def is_holiday?(date)
  @holiday_set.include?(date)
end 

  is_holiday?(date_str_to_obj("2015:04:04"))
    #=> false
  is_holiday?(date_str_to_obj("2015:04:05"))
    #=> true
```

Map each day of the week to an element of `day_groups`:

```
@day_group_by_dow = day_groups.each_with_object({}) { |(period,days),h|
  days.each { |d| h[d] = period } }
  #=> {1=>:weekdays, 2=>:weekdays, 3=>:weekdays, 4=>:weekdays,
  #    5=>:weekdays, 6=>:weekend,  0=>:weekend}
```

Map each element of `day_groups` to an array of work periods:

```
@work_periods_by_day_group = work_periods.each_with_object({}) { |(k,g),h|
  h.update(g[:day_group]=>[k]) { |_,nwp,owp| nwp+owp } }
  #=> {:weekdays=>[:weekday_graveyard, :weekday_day, :weekday_swing],
  #    :weekend=> [:weekends]}
```

Compute hours worked within a work period:

```
def start_and_end_times_to_hours(start_time, end_time)
  (time_to_minutes_after_midnight(end_time) - 
    time_to_minutes_after_midnight(start_time))/60.0
end

  start_and_end_times_to_hours("10:00", "14:30")
    #=> 4.5
```

A helper for the previous method:

```
private    
def time_to_minutes_after_midnight(time_str)
  hrs, mins = time_str.scan(/(\d\d):(\d\d)/).first.map(&:to_i)      
  60 * hrs + mins
end
public

  time_to_minutes_after_midnight("10:00")
    #=> 600
  time_to_minutes_after_midnight("14:30")
    #=> 870
```

As indicated by the method name:

```
def date_and_time_to_current_period(date, time, work_periods)
  day_grp = @day_group_by_dow[date.wday]
  periods = @work_periods_by_day_group[day_grp]
  periods.find do |per|
    p = work_periods[per]
    p[:start_time] <= time && time < p[:end_time]
  end
end

  date_and_time_to_current_period(date_str_to_obj("2015:04:03"),
    #=> :weekday_swing 
  date_and_time_to_current_period(date_str_to_obj("2015:04:04"),
    #=> :weekend
```

Lastly, another self-explanatory method:

```
def next_period_and_date_by_period_and_date(work_periods, period, date)
  end_time = work_periods[period][:end_time]
  if end_time == "24:00" # next_day
    day_grp = @day_group_by_dow[next_day(date.wday)]
    wp = @work_periods_by_day_group[day_grp]
    [wp.find { |period| work_periods[period][:start_time]=="00:00" }, date+1]
  else # same day
    day_grp = work_periods[period][:day_group]
    wp = @work_periods_by_day_group[day_grp]
    [wp.find { |period| work_periods[period][:start_time]==end_time }, date] 
  end
end

  next_period_and_date_by_period_and_date(work_periods,
    :weekday_day, date_str_to_obj("2015:04:03"))
    #=> [:weekday_swing, #<Date: 2015-04-03 ((2457116j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
  next_period_and_date_by_period_and_date(work_periods,
    :weekday_swing, date_str_to_obj("2015:04:02"))
    #=> [:weekday_graveyard, #<Date: 2015-04-03...+0s,2299161j)>] 
  next_period_and_date_by_period_and_date(work_periods,
    :weekday_swing, date_str_to_obj("2015:04:03"))
    #=> [:weekend, #<Date: 2015-04-04 ((2457117j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
  next_period_and_date_by_period_and_date(work_periods,
    :weekday_swing, date_str_to_obj("2015:04:04"))
    #=> [:weekend, #<Date: 2015-04-05 ((2457118j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

**Calculation of payroll**

```
shifts_worked.each_with_object(Hash.new(0.0)) do |shift, payroll|
  id = shift[:id]
  date = date_str_to_obj(shift[:date])
  start_time = shift[:start_time]
  end_time = shift[:end_time]
  wage_schedule = wage_by_job[employees[id][:job]]
  curr_period = date_and_time_to_current_period(date, start_time, work_periods)

  while true
    end_time_in_period = work_periods[curr_period][:end_time]
    end_time_in_period = end_time if
      (end_time > start_time && end_time < end_time_in_period)
    hours_in_period =
      start_and_end_times_to_hours(start_time, end_time_in_period)
    wage = wage_schedule[curr_period][is_holiday?(date) ? :holiday : :standard]
    payroll[id] += (wage * hours_in_period).round(2)
    break if end_time == end_time_in_period
    curr_period, date =
      next_period_and_date_by_period_and_date(work_periods,
        curr_period, date)
    start_time = work_periods[curr_period][:start_time]
  end
end
  #=> {123=>795.5, 221=>698.0}
```

Comment: Hi Cary, thanks so much for your detailed answer. To be honest, my hope was that someone would point me to a gem where someone smarter than myself had already solved this problem, but I guess such a thing doesn't exist yet. I will try and upload my current solution as an answer to show what I have so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following gem:
https://github.com/fnando/recurrence

I haven't done Holidays yet.

Requirement

```
class Requirement < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Model with attributes:
    # start - datetime
    # end - datetime
    # is_sleepin - boolean

    def duration
        self.end - self.start
    end

    def to_range
        self.start..self.end
    end

   def spans_multiple_days?
      self.end.to_date != self.start.to_date
   end

end
```

Breakdown of duration of requirement (shift)

```
class Breakdown

  attr_reader :requirement,
              :standard_total_duration,
              :weekend_total_duration,
              :wakein_total_duration

  def initialize(requirement)
    @requirement = requirement

    @rules = Array.new
    @rules << Breakdown::StandardRule.new(self)
    @rules << Breakdown::WeekendRule.new(self)

    @standard_total_duration = components[:standard].total_duration
    @weekend_total_duration = components[:weekend].total_duration

    if @requirement.is_sleepin?
      @standard_total_duration = 0
      @weekend_total_duration = 0
    end

    # Following is a special set of rules for certain Locations where staff work
    # If a requirement is_sleepin? that means duration is not counted so set to 0

    if ['Home 1', 'Home 2'].include?(@requirement.home.name.strip) and
      @requirement.spans_multiple_days? and not @requirement.is_sleepin?

        @rules << Aspirations::Breakdown::WakeinRule.new(self)
        @wakein_total_duration = components[:wakein].total_duration
        @standard_total_duration = 0
        @weekend_total_duration = 0
    end

  end

  def components
    @rules.hmap{ |k,v| [ k.to_sym, k ] }
  end

end
```

Which uses Rules to specify which parts of a shifts duration should be categorised:

```
module Breakdown
class Rule

  def initialize(breakdown)
    @requirement = breakdown.requirement
  end

  def to_sym
    # eg 'Breakdown::StandardRule' becomes :standard
    self.class.name.split('::').last.gsub("Rule", "").downcase.to_sym
  end

  def periods
    output = []
    occurrences = rule.events.map{ |e| rule_time_range(e) }
    occurrences.each do |o|
      if (o.max > @requirement.start and @requirement.end > o.min)
        output << (o & @requirement.to_range)
      end
    end
    return output
  end

  def total_duration
    periods.reduce(0) { |sum, p| sum + (p.max - p.min).to_i }
  end

end
end
```

Example of a Rule (in this case a weekend rule)

```
module Breakdown
class WeekendRule < Breakdown::Rule

  def period_expansion
    # This is an attempt to safely ensure that a weekend period
    # is detected even though the start date of the requirement
    # may be on Sunday evening, maybe could be just 2 days
    4.days
  end

  def period_range
    (@requirement.start.to_date - period_expansion)..(@requirement.end.to_date + period_expansion)
  end

  def rule
    Recurrence.new(:every => :week, :on => :saturday, :starts => period_range.min, :until => period_range.max)
  end

  def rule_time_range(date)
    # Saturday 8am
    start = date + Time.parse("08:00").seconds_since_midnight.seconds
    _end = (date + 1.day) + Time.parse("22:00").seconds_since_midnight.seconds
    start.._end
  end

end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach might be to break a week up into individual chunks of, say, 15 minutes (depending on how much resolution you need). Instead of ranges of time that are somewhat hard to deal with, you can then work with sets of these chunks, which Ruby supports very nicely.

Number the chunks of time sequentially:

Monday 12:00 AM-12:15 AM = 0
Monday 12:15 AM-12:30 AM = 1
...
Sunday 11:45 PM-12:00 AM = 671

Then prepare sets of integers for holidays, weekends, each shift, etc., whatever you need. Except for the holidays, those are probably all constants.

For instance, for your weekend from Saturday 8 AM to Sunday 10 PM:

weekend = [ 512..663 ]

Similarly, represent each employee's attendance as a set. For instance, somebody who worked from 8 AM to noon on Monday and from 10 AM to 11 AM on Saturday would be:

attendance = [ 32..47, 520..523 ]

With this approach, you can use set intersections to figure out how many hours were on weekends:

weekendAttendance = weekend & attendance

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks Kevin. How would this work for shifts that start on Sunday and finish on Monday?

Comment: I used week just as an example for illustration purposes; you can use month or any other period you like. Week of course is easy to work with because weekends always fall at the same point in time. That said, it may make sense to use whatever you use as pay periods. It may be two weeks, or it may be half of a month, however the company handles payroll. How does payroll handle shifts that start in one pay period and end in the next? You could handle it with overlapping time periods, but then you have to make sure you don't double pay. Or you can split such shifts.